# Org Mode .odt Export with em Dash

Tags: org-mode, org-export, libreoffice

When I export an .org file to .odt, it changes my em dashes (---) as expected (which is great for HTML). However, the .odt file in this case needs to retain standard manuscript format em dashes ( -- ) unfixed. Basically a space, two hyphens, and a space.

Trying to get this result:

**In org mode:** Application of em dash here---looks like that.

**Export to LibreOffice:** Application of em dash here -- looks like that.

If possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would probably be to add

```
#+OPTIONS: -:nil
```

to the file.  This will disable conversion of all *special strings* like `--` (to `–`) and `...` (to `…`).